# radial mirroring issues

Tags: modifiers

[image: what i get with the mirroring]

[image: what i want to achieve, but on all pillars]

i would like to mirror the cylinders facing the center branching off of the outer ones, but i cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: For clarity, please indicate your desired end result, somehow.

Comment: I did indicate my desired result.